# Query to get the failoverCount and lastFailover in a Windows Failover Cluster

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, cluster, failover, failovercluster, windows-cluster

Anyone know of a command or PowerShell script to get the current failoverCount and lastFailover datetime in a Windows Failover Cluster? I have a 2-node cluster that doesn't automatically failover sometimes. The group is configured with the default values of max 1 failure every 6 hours. After reviewing the log files from `Get-ClusterLog` I've seen a pattern:

When it works and successfuly does a failover to the other node, the log file will have:

- time since last failure is greater than failover period; resetting failoverCount to 0.
- Failing over group ME-AG, failoverCount 1, last time 2020/09/17-00:00:23.017.

When it fails and the cluster resources go down, the log file will have:

- Not failing over group ME-AG, failoverCount 2, failoverThresholdSetting 4294967295, lastFailover 1601/01/01-00:00:00.000

The lastFailover date being 410 years ago is probably because it's currently a null value. `Get-ClusterGroup ME-AG` shows the values for `FailoverPeriod` and `FailoverThreshold` but I can't seem to dig out where WSFC is getting the values for failoverCount and lastFailover.

Comment: Possibly related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131634/availability-group-how-to-determine-last-failover-time

Comment: Thanks @DougDeden `Get-WinEvent` does show the dates of the failovers but it doesn't match the lastFailover date, obviously. My server keeps 10 days of those logs but I had this happen with only 8 days between events, so it shouldn't have been a null value if it was using that same call.